# What is @id as passed to $resource?

Tags: angularjs

```
$resource("/entries/:id", {id: "@id"}, {update: {method: "PUT"}})
```

What is @id?

On the $resource [doc page](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource) someone says this below, but I still don't understand.

> If the parameter value is prefixed with @ then the value of that
>   parameter is extracted from the data object (useful for non-GET
>   operations)." The data object here refers to the `postData`object if
>   non-GET "class" action is used, or the instance itself if non-GET
>   instance action is used.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, and I may not, the parameter `{id: @id}` is an illustration of another way to supply your url variable with a piece of data.

Given this method:

```
var myResource = $resource("/posts/:theName", 
                           {theName: '@petName'},
                           {enter : {
                                      method: "POST", 
                                      isArray: false
                                     }
                            });
```

If I have an attribute "petName" in the data that I'm posting, the value of that attribute will be placed in `:theName` variable in my url.  Imagine the post data being `{"petType": "cat", "petName": "Spot"}`, the url will read `"/posts/Spot"`.  In my mind, the `@` means "attribute" of the object to be posted.

Take away the `@` from that value, and the url variable will directly reference the value in that resource parameter:

```
{theName: 'petName'} //no "@"
// url output ---->   '/posts/petName'
```

.

Here is the chain of references:

```
//url var--> //$resource param {..}  --->//Object to be posted
:theName---> {theName ----> @petName ---> {petName---> "Spot"
```

It only took 5 steps to get "Spot" into the url!

.

Example of a resource instance using the above example:

```
var postData = new myResource();
    postData.petType = "cat";
    postData.petName = "Spot";
    postData.$enter({}, function(data){
        $scope.data = data;
    })
    // url to post to will be '/posts/Spot', postData object will be 
    //  {"petType":"cat", "petName:"Spot"}
```

On a side note, the docs can be very confusing.  Have you ever taken a difficult course and the professor was a brilliant man who barely spoke your language? Yup.

Comment: thanks, i think i get it...seems like it would make more sense to create a "class" and have that inherit from resource...its almost like this is a member variable, but maybe thats murky too

Comment: The whole thing is murky.  There are about 4 different places where you can add url parameters.  When I write a resource I make it as simple and small as possible. Anything big and I use $http.  But that's just me...

Answer (score 0):

```
var myResource = $resource("/entries/:theName", 
                           {theName: '@petName'},
                           {update : {
                                      method: "PUT", 
                                      isArray: false
                                     }
                            });
```

Comment: Please explain your lines of code so other users can understand its functionality. Thanks!