# What is the use of @ in Angular $resource

Tags: angularjs

This is from the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource).

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
var user = User.get({userId:123}, function() {
  user.abc = true;
  user.$save();
});
```

What does `@id` mean? If we are supposed to supply `userId` as an argument as specified by `/:userId`, why specifying this rule again in `{userId: '@id'}`, assuming that's what it means.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS $resource @ prefixed parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187823/angularjs-resource-prefixed-parameter)

Comment: Read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313971/at-sign-in-parameter-names-in-resource-definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the `:userId` will be removed from url if not present on the `$resource` call, as written in docs:

> If the parameter value is prefixed with @ then the value of that parameter is extracted from the data object (useful for non-GET operations).

Comment: Sorry I have been working non stop for 24+ hrs. For the love of God, I didn't either see this line in the documentation and the SO question which asks the same thing. Thanks anyway.